# Alter large table on Aurora Serverless MySQL

Tags: alter-table, aws-aurora-serverless

We use AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL v2.07.1. We would like to alter one of our table and add a column to this table.

The issue is that the table contains more than 500 Millions rows, which gives us a timeout error (~45 seconds) when we try to alter the table.

```
ALTER TABLE studentAidProgram ADD details TEXT
```

We don't have any index that allows us to sort the entire table and migrate it to a new table with the new schema. And the timeout issue does not allow us to add a new index.

Does someone has an idea/tool of how we can alter this large table on Aurora Serverless ?